# Do spells stack when placed on top of each other?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I were to drop two spells (rage or heals) on top of each other, do they stack?   If so, what is the % increase for rage / what is the total healed for heal spells? (just x2?)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spells don't stack, but they do work together in a way. At least some of them do.

Lightning spells deal set damage. So you just deal the damage from two if you use two, no multiplier.

Heal spells are not actually time dependent, but hit-points healed dependent. So placing two down will, from a point of view, stack. The units gain double benefits, but not more than that.

Rage spells don't stack in any way, they are time dependent. The only reason to overlap them is for continued rage.

Jump spells are just like rage spells, they're time dependent, and there's no benefit to overlap except for allowing units to move further

Freeze spells are also time dependent, so same deal.

So essentially it's just heal spells.

Comment: Are you sure healing spells are time dependent? The wiki says that [it lasts for a total of 12 seconds (healing 'pulses' every 0.3 seconds).](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Spell)

Comment: @EpicGuy There is no timer on Heal Spells. It just so happens that it lasts 12 seconds, but this 12 seconds is the result of hitpoints being healed. If one Heal Spell heals 800HP over 12 seconds, two spells on the same spot heal 1600HP over 12 seconds. So it ends up lasting for a set amount of time, but the time is not actually a boundary. True, if no units are in the heal space, it still runs out, but the 800 vs 1600 still applies, which is the pseudo-stacking effect.

Comment: Ah sorry made an error on my comment, meant to ask "Are you sure healing spells **aren't** time dependent?". What do you mean there is no timer on Heal Spells? Sorry if I'm misinterpreting.

Comment: @EpicGuy That's the question I answered. It is HP based, even though it only lasts a certain amount of time. That's a little confusing. The point is that the driving force behind the Heal Spell is HP, so it "stacks." It's true they only last 12 seconds, but there's no timer that counts down from 12 when you deploy a spell. It's based on HP output.

Comment: @Tech Hey, I know this is old, and the game's been updated since your answers and comments, but I'm still confused by what you mean when they last 12 seconds but don't actually have a timer that counts this down?? Or is this not applicable anymore?

Comment: @user3052786 Wow, it's been a while since I played clash... Basically the idea is that heal spells have a set amount that they heal, dealing a set amount of healing every 0.3 seconds. So that creates an effective timer if you want to look at it that way. I have no idea if the game still works this way.

Comment: @TechnoSam hey, thanks for replying! I only just recently got into the game, and I was confused because the stats for the heal spell only lists "total heal" I expected it to stay until the amount was used up, but do I understand correctly that it will "heal" every 0.3 seconds regardless of whether troops are under it or not, then disappear? So I guess whichever one comes first, the total heal used, or the effective "duration"?

Comment: @user3052786 Yeah, sorry this is pretty confusing, but I think you've almost got it. It will heal every 0.3 seconds regardless of whether troops are under it or not, but each unit gets that heal. So that amount of healing will always be used up in the same amount of time. But with more units under the spell, the actual number of hitpoints healed rises. Make sense? So if you have four giants under one heal spell, it's definitely possible to get 3200hp healed from one spell across all four units.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the heal spell won't stop until it's healed 800hp to everything stranding on it in that period of time it's there. Rage spells and the above only rages etc the amount its upgraded for for the amount of times it's upgraded to.